# php preg_replace with exceptions

Tags: php

I have a string with some tekst enrichement, zo there are `<b>` and `<em>` and some other html tags in the string. Of course a user could also put `<script>` or other stuf into the string, but that is not what you want. I want to replace the `<` and `>` by `&lt;` and `&gt;`, but not the `<b>` and `<em>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want a negative lookahead:

```
$escaped = preg_replace("(</?(?!(?:b|em)\b))","&lt;",$raw);
```

Note that you don't need to escape `>` to `&gt;` because it has no meaning on its own.

Comment: Tested it with this string ("Dus&dus<b>test</b>") and doesn't work,also replaces the <b>

Comment: this would be the perfect sollution because it's pretty lightweigth. Do jou know whats wrong in your code?

Comment: Try adding `/?` right after the `<` in the regex, and replace the space between the `) )` with `)\b)`. I wasn't thinking properly XD

Comment: YEAH! This is it! Small adjustement, i removed the \B and added /b and /em after em

Answer (score 1):

test this

```
  $notecomments=" <b> <em> <sf> <script>";
  $output=preg_replace_callback(array("#<(.*?)>#"),function($matches){
switch($matches[1]){
    case 'b':
    case 'em':
      return $matches[0];
    break;
    default:
      return "&lt;".$matches[1]."&gt;";

}
},' '.$notecomments.' ');
  print_r($output);
```

output:

```
   <b> <em> &lt;sf&gt; &lt;script&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) fits better for this:

```
echo strip_tags($text, '<b><em>');
```